# How to start WSO2 in back ground in Unix

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

How to start WSO2 API Manager in background? I start it by

```
$ sh wso2server.sh
```

How to make it run in background so that it wont be stopped when I exit my putty terminal?

Comment: Maybe you'd like to [create a service](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Installing+as+a+Linux+Service)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the nohup command to run the script as a background process.

```
 nohup ./wso2server.sh &
```

It would write all the logs you get on terminal to a file nohup.out in the same directory where you run your wso2server.sh script file.

Answer (score 0):

Following will help you, It's similar to any other Linux scripts.

```
sh wso2server.sh start > /dev/null &
```

Additionally, you can start any WSO2 products as Linux services. Please refer [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Installing+as+a+Linux+Service).

Comment: That will make it stop when the terminal is closed rite?

Comment: Starting as Linux service is the best option. No, it won't stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the command `./wso2server.sh --start` or `./wso2server.sh --stop`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ./wso2server.sh start > /dev/null &